# Is it possible to use select(mtcars, wt:) to select all variables from wt till the end?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm sure I came across syntax like this using dplyr before but could not find it after some Googling.

Using the colon ':' I can select from one variable to another e.g.

```
mtcars %>% select_at(vars(wt:carb)) %>% head
                     wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

carb is also the last variable in mtcars. Is there a way of using the colon like so:

```
mtcars %>% select(wt: ) %>% head
```

To denote selecting all variables from wt onwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest I can think of is `mtcars %>% select(wt:ncol(.))`

Answer (score 1):

In base `R` you could do:

```
cols <- match("wt", names(mtcars)):ncol(mtcars)
mtcars[cols]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
mtcars %>% select(wt:carb)
```

so using `select` instead of `select_at`.